# authentication to MQ via mqseries library php

Tags: php, ibm-mq, password-protection

I need some help with php mqseries library. 
I have some troubles connecting to Queue-manager. It does connect without authentication, but when I'm trying to use MQCSP, I get

> 2035 error.

I've contacted the developers, one of them told me that he no longer works on it, others don't respond.
It looks like on IBM it doesn't work.

Here is my connection code:

```
    $cfg = array();
$cfg['ESB_ADDRESS']                = '10.4.116.110(1416)';
$cfg['ESB_CHANNEL']                = 'SITEEXT.SVRCONN';
$cfg['ESB_QUEUE_MANAGER']          = 'IIB.ADP.MI1';
$cfg['ESB_QUEUE_NAME']             = 'SITEEXT_TO_ESB';
$cfg['ESB_TOPIC_STRING']           = '';
$cfg['USERID']                                           = 'svcgo-site';
$cfg['PASSWORD']                   = 'site91';
$cfg['QMgrName']                                   = 'IIB.ADP.MI1';
$cfg['DiscInterval']                           = '10';
/*
$cfg['ESB_ADDRESS']                = '10.4.111.139(1414)';
$cfg['ESB_CHANNEL']                = 'SITEEXT.SVRCONN';
$cfg['ESB_QUEUE_MANAGER']          = 'QM01';
$cfg['ESB_QUEUE_NAME']             = 'TEST_QUEUE1';
//$cfg['ESB_QUEUE_NAME']             = 'SITEEXT_TO_ESB';
$cfg['ESB_TOPIC_STRING']           = '';
$cfg['USERID']                                           = 'svcgo-site';
$cfg['PASSWORD']                   = 'site91';
//$cfg['QMgrName']                                   = 'QM01';
$cfg['DiscInterval']                           = '10';
*/

$connectionOptions = array(
    'StrucId' => MQSERIES_MQCNO_STRUC_ID,
        'Version' => MQSERIES_MQCNO_CURRENT_VERSION,
        'Options' => MQSERIES_MQCNO_STANDARD_BINDING,
        //MQSERIES_USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION,
        'MQCD' => array(
                        //'Version' => MQSERIES_MQCD_VERSION_11,
                        'ChannelName' => $cfg['ESB_CHANNEL'],
                        'TransportType' => MQSERIES_MQXPT_TCP,
                        'ConnectionName' => $cfg['ESB_ADDRESS']
        ),
        MQSERIES_USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION => true,
        MQSERIES_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION => true,
        USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP => true,
        USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION => true,
        MQSERIES_USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP => true,
        useMQCSPAuthentication => true,
        'MQCSP' => array( 
                        'Version' => MQSERIES_MQCSP_CURRENT_VERSION,
                        'StrucId' => MQSERIES_MQCSP_STRUC_ID,
                        'AuthenticationType' => MQSERIES_MQCSP_AUTH_USER_ID_AND_PWD,
                        'CSPUserIdPtr' => $cfg['USERID'],
                        'CSPUserIdLength' => strlen($cfg['USERID']),
                        'CSPPasswordLength' => strlen($cfg['PASSWORD']),
                        'CSPPasswordPtr' => $cfg['PASSWORD']
        ),
        /*
           'ClientConnPtr' => array(
                        //'Version' => MQSERIES_MQCD_VERSION_11,
                        'ChannelName' => $cfg['ESB_CHANNEL'],
                        'TransportType' => MQSERIES_MQXPT_TCP,
                        'ConnectionName' => $cfg['ESB_ADDRESS']
        ) 
        */
);
mqseries_connx($cfg['ESB_QUEUE_MANAGER'], $connectionOptions, $connection, $completionCode, $reason);
if ($completionCode !== MQSERIES_MQCC_OK) {
    die("Connx CompCode : {$completionCode} Reason : {$reason} Text : " . mqseries_strerror($reason));
}
else{echo "Good<br>";}
```

Php v.5.3.17

IBM MQ 9

Mqseries client library v 0.15.0

Comment: Also to note that all the various combinations of MQSERIES_USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION, MQSERIES_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION, USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, USE_MQCSP_AUTHENTICATION, MQSERIES_USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, and useMQCSPAuthentication would probably not be involved if per Mark someone were to extend this library to support MQCSP.  These all look like variations of the settings that either IBM MQ Classes for Java, IBM MQ Classes for JMS, or the IBM MQ .NET classes use to tell them to send the MQCSP structure.  The MQI C libraries do not have such a setting, the MQCSP just needs to be referenced.

Answer (score 0):

That PHP package does not have the code in it to handle the MQCSP structure and add it to the CNO. Looks like you would need to modify the _mqseries_set_mqcno_from_array function and how it is called.